# Please help me with this error I got "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I need help with this error. So I watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzM7zIIeH8Y) on youtube, on minutes 2:40 to 8:01. The error I got is this

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

**this is my code (the code is the same as the tutorial, just the link is different)**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List> rssToJson(String category,
    {String baseUrl = 'https://www.cnnindonesia.com/nasional/rss'}) async {
  var client = http.Client();
  final myTranformer = Xml2Json();
  return await client.get(baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml').then((Response) {
    return Response.body;
  }).then((bodyString) {
    myTranformer.parse(bodyString);
    var json = myTranformer.toGData();
    return jsonDecode(json)['rss']['channel']['item'];
  });
}
```

I got a red underline on this code

```
return await client.get(baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml').then((Response)
```

this is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: lah
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.4
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  bubble_bottom_bar: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  xml2json: ^5.3.2
  flutter:
    SDK: flutter

dev_dependencies:

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/icons/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
      - family: Times
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/times_news_roman/Times New Roman 400.ttf
            weight: 400
          - asset: assets/fonts/times_news_roman/Times New Roman Gras 700.ttf
            weight: 700
      - family: Avenir
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/avenir/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf
            weight: 400
          - asset: assets/fonts/avenir/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.otf
            weight: 500
          - asset: assets/fonts/avenir/AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.otf
            weight: 600
          - asset: assets/fonts/avenir/avenir-next-lt-pro-bold.otf
            weight: 700
      - family: League
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/league_spartan/LeagueSpartan-Bold.otf
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

currently, I'm using the new version of Flutter SDK, the 2.10.1 version. Please help me. I need the solution as soon as possible.
Thank you

Edit: here is my [github link](https://github.com/DarkNike68/NewsApp), if you had any solution why the news is not showing up. Please tell me

Comment: You need to create a `Uri` object from the `baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml'`. Maybe you can do `Uri.parse(baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml')`.

Comment: To be exact, `return await client.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml')).then((Response)`. Please try that. For your reference, Please check the example/documentation of [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

Answer (score 0):

client.get() method expects a Uri and you are passing String in it

```
client.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + category + '/rssfeed.xml'))
```

Comment: When I implement your solution to my code, there is no error. But, the news is not showing up.